# how to restrict show action in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In routes:

```
resources :service_requests

get 'service_requests/get_mobile_number' => "service_requests#get_mobile_number",:as=>"get_mobile_number"
```

In service_requests_controller:

```
before_action :set_service_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

def find_mobile_number

end
```

In view:

```
<%= link_to get_mobile_number_path,:remote=>true do %>
```

In log:

```
Started GET "/service_requests/get_mobile_number" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-16 12:22:30 +0530
Processing by ServiceRequestsController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"get_mobile_number"}
```

I want get "/service_requests/get_mobile_number" path after clicked on the link.But while clicking on this link, it redirect me to the show action which i don't want.How do i restrict show action.Please help me out.

Comment: why are you using `:remote => true` in your link? please post entire link_to code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after interchange the routes:

```
get 'service_requests/get_mobile_number' => "service_requests#get_mobile_number",:as=>"get_mobile_number"

resources :service_requests
```